# Is it possible to overclock the baudrate from the mega to 230400 bps?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, baud-rate

i have a Arduino Mega 2560 and want send data with 230400bps to my laptop without any framingerror.

I want send the data over USB with serial.print ist that possible or must i use the ethernet?

When that is possible it will be really nice when someone can write what i have to do.

With friendly wishes sniffi

Comment: This might interest you; http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=150299.555. See section on UART optimization and the benchmark https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/examples/Benchmarks/CosaBenchmarkUARTburst/CosaBenchmarkUARTburst.ino. What effective baud-rate are you looking for?

Comment: I need 230400 bps, my protocol has 38400 and i add 5 bytes (4 timestamp 1 byte filled with flags) so 6*38400= 230400 i think.

Comment: The error rate at 230400 bps with system clock 16 MHz is very high. 250000 bps is much better. Please see the AVR baud-rate calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to overclock the baudrate from the mega to 230400 bps?

Yes, setting that baud-rate is not a problem but this specific baud-rate may will give a high error rate. According to the AVR baud-rate calculation (UBRRn Settings for 16 Mhz system clock) the error is 8.5% (U2Xn=0) and -3.5% (U2Xn=1).

Simply choosing 250000 bps will remove this error.

Cheers!

Comment: Ok i can use 250kbps that will be work but what means -3.5% is 0% not the best?

Comment: How can i change the baudrate? I have switch the buffer from 8 bit to 16 bit because i need the second byte for my statusbit´s (e.g. my 9 bit protocol), is that still possible?

Comment: The error is generated sampling frequency relative optimal. Negative (as -3.5%) means the generated frequency is too low. To change the baudrate see Serial.begin() https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin

Comment: You need to open a new question for the 8 to 16 bit. That is a new "can of worms". And you need to acknowledge if you think the original question has been answered :)